# Powershell accessing an object in AD SearchResultCollection

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell code:

```
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$directorySearche.PageSize = 100
$directorySearcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::SubTree
$searchResults = $directorySearcher.FindAll()
#$searchResults
$searchResults.Item(0).Path
```

If I uncomment `#$searchResults` then I can see hundreds of entries with "Path" and "Properties" as the objects' properties.
However when `$searchResults.Item(0).Path` is executed, it just says "Running script/selection. Press ctrl+break to stop." and has been like that for 10 mins so far.

Why can't I access an individual object from the `SearchResultCollection` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were just way too many results.

I used a filter to narrow it down and now I can access individual objects since there are now only 347 results.

Before I couldn't even find out the count because there were too many.

Comment: For anyone that arrives here, I've run into this with only 225 items. -Eventually- I could iterate over the collection, but it took minutes.